# Difference between Composite Non-clustered Index and Non-clustered Include - Index tree architecture difrence

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, indexing

I am trying to google it from couple hours and it still is not clear for me.

What is the difference between:

```
Create Index NonClusteredComposit_IDX ON Table(id,quantity,price)
Create Index NonClusteredCompositAndInclude_IDX ON Table(id) Include (price,quantity).
```

On the Index lvl only.

I understand how they work and even when to use them.

But that I can't understand is that how data is stored inside the NonClusteredCompositAndInclude_IDX?

What would change on this schema where:
Index page contains Indexed data (id,quantity,price) and pointer to RID (when a table is a heap) or pointer to a page in B-tree (for B-tree/Clustered tables).

[image]

From the documentation, I know that when I include columns then data are stored in Leaf node but I don't see any difference between this and normal Index On(1,2,3) if we are talking about architecture inside Index.

Can anyone can describe me differences in index architecture?
Thanks!

Comment: The difference between your two indexes comes down to which data is included in the index as a part of the index key and just included as data on the leaf nodes.

Comment: On an index _without_ an include, only a pointer to the clustered index (or heap rowid) is stored - basically a pointer the to full row. On an index with an include, rather than a pointer to the entire row (requiring a bookmark lookup), just the included data is stored.

Answer (score 5):

In first approach, sorting will be on these three attributes - id,quantity,price

In second approach, sorting will be on "id" only but that "id" contains values of "quantity,price" hence it does not require to do key lookup or rid lookup to get the respective attributes.

To illustrate this if you create below indexes in one of the tables, both does Index seek but if you check the number of rows read, it differs as one takes from sorted data and the 2nd approach does full scan for selected "id"

[image]

On checking Number of reads for the first index...

[image]

On checking Number of reads for the 2nd index it proves that it does full scan of index for the seek'd data, hence you get 188 records

[image]

Comment: That is what I was looking for! Thank you Kannnan

Comment: Added details with illustration

Comment: Excellent answer.